# How to generate query string in golang?

Tags: http, go, url, query-string

In my use-case, I need to post data to url, however the data itself is a query string.
Example:

`curl -POST -d "username=abc&rememberme=on&authtype=intenal" "https..somemdpoint"`

What I have is a method which takes in 3 values

```
function makePostRequest(username string, rememberme string, authtype string, endpoint string) {
  // post a curl request.
}
```

I am struggling to find any library that would return me a query string if I provided it with parameters.

I tried doing this:

```
q := req.URL.Query()
q.Add("api_key", "key_from_environment_or_flag")
q.Add("another_thing", "foobar")
fmt.Print(q)
```

But realized it actually returns Values which is a map so its no good.

Is there any method in golang that creates a queryString ?

Comment: Your curl example would send the data as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload, are you sure you want it in the query string (as part of the URL)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You almost got it.  Call [`Values.Encode()`](https://godoc.org/net/url#Values.Encode) to encode the map in URL-encoded form.

```
fmt.Print(q.Encode()) // another_thing=foobar&api_key=key_from_environment_or_flag
```

Create the map directly instead of using `req.URL.Query()` to return an empty map:

```
values := url.Values{}
values.Add("api_key", "key_from_environment_or_flag")
values.Add("another_thing", "foobar")
query := values.Encode()
```

Use `strings.NewReader(query)` to get an `io.Reader` for the POST request body.